# Publishing Near Tool as a GP Service in ArcGIS Server 10

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

I am curious if someone has successfully published Near Tool as a service. This tool is located in Analysis Tools > Proximity. The tool updates the input layer it doesnot have an output layer. I am not sure if this possible or if there is a workaround.

Appreciate any ideas.

Thanks
Jay

Comment: This question will receive a better answer at [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Jay,

all tools have an output. If you don't see one in the user interface it is because it is considered a derived parameter/output. For more information please take a look at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000063000000.

Once you place the tool inside a model you can specify the inputs and outputs explicitly. The complete sharing workflows are outlined and detailed with screen captures at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005700000047000000

- Thomas

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for the feedback. The near tool when run from ArcInfo, adds a field in one of the input layers and adds values in it. The output in this case is actually an added field in input layer...unless there is way to have tool generate an output layer with added field?